# How do I change the size and color of the stage in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

AFAIK, in AS2 it was "Stage.height = x;".

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of [`flash.display.stage`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html) in AS3:

> The Stage object is not globally accessible. You need to access it through the stage property of a DisplayObject instance.

Also refer to this: [Setting Stage properties](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_10.html)

Answer (score 2):

You really can't... the background color is not really a stage property, you should work-around it by changing some background clip.
As for the size, in AIR you can directly change the NativeWindow dimesions, but in a browser you need to use javascript to change the object's size:

```
document.getElementById("myFlash").height=100;
```

<strike>You could use stage.width = 100, but it will only change the displayobject's dimensions, truncating its content, and leaving an empty space next to it...</strike>
Actually Stage.width is read-only in AS3 and AS2.

Comment: While it isn't the answer I was looking for, it is the right answer. Realizing that it is basically readonly through ActionScript. You can set it in Flash CS4 right off the bat, so I don't understand why they made it this way. AS3 is a huge improvement anyway, but there are still kinks they gotta iron out.

Comment: +"saved me from an even worse headache than I already had" right after "ActionScript"

Comment: AFAK the behaviour is exactly the same as in AS2... Stage.width was also read-only in AS2 (I just realized that in AS3 it is overwritten as read-only for the Stage).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you are compiling your .swf, but it is completely possible. If you are building a Flex project, you can set the `backgroundColor` property of the `Application` or use a css file to change it. e.g.

```
<mx:Application 
    backgroundColor="#000000" 
    width="500"
    height="500"
    layout="absolute"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

</mx:Application>
```

If you are building in Flex (an "Actionscript Project") or using the mxmlc compiler, you can use the undocumented "SWF" metadata tag, e.g.

```
package
{
    [SWF(width="500", height="500", backgroundColor="#000000")]
    public class MyApp extends Sprite
    {

    }
}
```

And of course, if you're using Flash "the application", you can just click the stage and then go to the properties panel and set the width, height, and background color.

Comment: Note that none of those are ActionScript. Both translate to compiler directives, and neither is executed at runtime.

Comment: Haha, oops! *Votes self down*

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. In the main CData block, "this" is the application object. Then:

```
this.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xff0000);
```

This is much better than starting to creates sprites and rendering with the graphics layer, since presumably the best performance is with a flat fill in the absence of any objects in front.